Have I got these #if #endif statement blocks wrong?
I'm trying to figure out which CPP standard the compiler is using, when I compile on Windows this works, but when I compile on Linux nothing gets set and the vale remains 0. Am I doing something wrong?
#define CPP_STANDARD 0L

#ifdef _WIN32 // WIN32 START
#if _MSVC_LANG == 202002L
#define CPP_STANDARD 2020
#elif _MSVC_LANG == 201703L
#define CPP_STANDARD 2017
#elif _MSVC_LANG == 201402L
#define CPP_STANDARD 2014
#endif // WIN32 ENDIF

#else // NOT WIN32 START
#if __cplusplus == 202002L
#define CPP_STANDARD 2020
#elif __cplusplus == 201703L
#define CPP_STANDARD 2017
#elif __cplusplus == 201402L
#define CPP_STANDARD 2014
#elif __cplusplus == 201103L
#define CPP_STANDARD 2011
#endif
#endif // NOT WIN32 ENDIF

#if CPP_STANDARD == 0L
#error "No CPP Standard detected"
#endif

Edit: I found out that GCC is setting the __cplusplus flag to 201709 but I'm checking for 201703. I guess I should be checking >= 201700???

What version of g++ are you running? What do you get if  you print the value of __cplusplus?

Wait... I edited out the C tag to match the C++ focus, but are you compiling *.c files by any chance?

You should #undef CPP_STANDARD before redefining it.

Using all of those macros qualifies as wrong in my view. Why would you do that?

@JesperJuhl The reason I did it like this is so that anywhere in my code I can do #if CPP_STANDARD < 2020 ... so and so, as opposed to #ifdef WIN32 && __cplusplus < 202002 ... it looks worse, and 202002 doesn't mean anything to me

long val = __cplusplus; std::cout << val;  What is output when you do this?

one should know that MSVC compiler got  __cplusplus  wrong by default by design, it requires /Zc:__cplusplus flag

First, you need to remove the line #define CPP_STANDARD 0L otherwise you will end up with a macro redefinition.
You can confirm that the code works as expected in Compiler Explorer (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qPG7T9TGE) returning correct version of the C++ standard. I checked MSVC, clang, and gcc.
#ifdef _WIN32 // WIN32 START
    #if _MSVC_LANG == 202002L
    #define CPP_STANDARD 2020
    #elif _MSVC_LANG == 201703L
    #define CPP_STANDARD 2017
    #elif _MSVC_LANG == 201402L
    #define CPP_STANDARD 2014
    #endif // WIN32 ENDIF
#else // NOT WIN32 START
    #if __cplusplus == 202002L
    #define CPP_STANDARD 2020
    #elif __cplusplus == 201703L
    #define CPP_STANDARD 2017
    #elif __cplusplus == 201402L
    #define CPP_STANDARD 2014
    #elif __cplusplus == 201103L
    #define CPP_STANDARD 2011
    #endif
#endif

#ifndef CPP_STANDARD
#error "No CPP Standard detected"
#endif

int main()
{
    return CPP_STANDARD;
}


most MSVC versions require Zc:__cplusplus or they always will report 1 or C++98  regardless of sctual standard active

Thank you. It turns out GCC was defining __cplusplus as 201709 and I was checking for 201703. I guess I'm supposed to check >= 201700?

@Zebrafish apparently some versions of clang report 201707! If you can, you really should not rely on the value of __cplusplus, since compilers don't always conform to what the standard says it should be. At least newer versions of C++ try to address this with feature-specific macros instead, so try to use those instead when possible.

Check "Predefined macros" on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace for the list of values. I don't know what g++ wants to tell you with the 201709 value -- possibly indicating some extension. In general, you'll want to check for "at least C++17" anyway, as opposed to just "exactly C++17" -- although there are more specific feature macros as well. Likewise, if I wanted C++17 precisely, I would still check for a value at least C++17 and not larger than C++20...
